# infinite series limit ratio, where the one in numerator converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is it true that if we know that a series $\sum a_n$ converges, that series $\sum b_n$ diverges, that $a_n \ge 0$, and that $b_n > 0$, that then $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 0$?

I thought we could prove with assuming that the limit is not 0, so it is either a constant $\ne 0$ or tends to infinity. If it is constant $\ne 0$, then by the usual limit test, we $\sum b_n$ also converges, which contradicts the original assumption. If it tends to infinity, then $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{b_n}{a_n} = 0$, which implies that $b_n$ converges, which again contradicts the original assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counter-example: $a_n=\frac 1 {n^{2}} \forall n$, $b_n=a_n$ if $n$ is even and $b_n=1$ if $n$ is odd.

Comment: Thanks! Is the problem in my proof that I assumed that the limit exists?

Comment: If the limit is assumed to exist then the conclusion holds. @S11n